# edit and add a frame to floatbutton

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

I wanted to ask how you can get a row layout like this, and then how we can change the floatbutton so as to obtain a result similar to the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spMdP.jpg)

I tried to extend the floatbutton class and tweaking various settings but without success. I'm sorry for my English

Comment: Can you share your floatbutton  xml ?

Comment: What is the question ? How to design the XML ? How to get a circular image ?

Comment: yes, I would like to know how to put a circle around the floatbutton